# Where do I set which template file to use for a block?

Tags: theming, blocks

I know I can just override block.tpl.php using the normal template system. But is there a way to set the tpl file when I define a block in my module ?

I thinking of an equivalent to this:

```
function theming_example_theme() {
  return array(
    'theming_example_text_form'  => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      // In this one the rendering will be done by a tpl.php file instead of
      // being rendered by a function, so we specify a template.
      'template' => 'theming_example_text_form',
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Most of the times I just do

```
$block['subject'] = t('My block title');
$block['content'] = theme('my_custom_theme', $block_content);

return $block;
```

from `hook_block_view()` function if you're making a module that creates a block. The theme function `my_custom_theme` can use a template file such as `my-custom-theme-block.tpl.php`. Also you can suggest theme hooks through `hook_preprocess_block`. Just check for the delta of your own block and set a theme hook there.

```
function HOOK_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['block']->delta == 'my-block-delta') {
    $vars['template_suggestions'][] = 'my-custom-theme-block';
  }
}
```

Comment: Additionally, choosing which template file to use is the theme layer's job. If you hard-code it in your block definition function, no one will be able to override it in their theme later, whereas if you define it as a custom theme function, the active theme can override it.

Comment: @theunraveler If the theme function hardcoded into `HOOK_block_view` defines a template file, it should be overridable if you just create a same name file in your theme directory. `template_suggestions` also work the same way. Drupal will know that `my-custom-theme-block.tpl.php` in your theme directory will override `my-custom-theme-block.tpl.php` in the module directory.

Comment: Right...I was supporting your answer and giving a further reason why yours is the best practice. Sorry that wasn't clearer :-)

Comment: I guess we both misunderstood each other :) Thanks for the addition. Much appreciated.

Comment: So is this preferable to using e.g. `block--themename--delta.tpl.php` and not implementing book_block_view() at all?